# undefined reference to 'xcb_event_get_label'

Tags: c, x11, xcb

I have `#included <xcb/xcb.h>` and `<xcb/xcb_util.h>` and linked with `-lxcb` but I still get an

`undefined reference to 'xcb_event_get_label'`

I can see the function exists in the header file, and the error indicates a linker error, but what other libraries do I need to link against?

Comment: adding the **full, verbatim** compiler output might help.

Comment: also, intuition says there's a library called xcb-util, xcb_util or xcbutil that you should also link against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking with `-lxcb-util` did the trick as mentioned by [Marcus Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4433386/marcus-m%C3%BCller)